# What does "Precision: White = nn%, Black = nn%" mean in a game broadcast by chessbase.com?

Tags: chessbase, annotation

The game "*Salgado L, Iván vs Arroyo R, Jesús, 83rd ESP-ch 1-0*", shows this annotation after the last move:

> Precision: White = 93%, Black = 18%.

What does that phrase mean?

Check https://es.chessbase.com/post/sabrina-vega-y-salvador-del-rio-de-angelis-campeones-de-ajedrez-de-espana-2018 for more information.

Answer (score 2):

It surely is a measure of the quality of play, the deviation of the game from a "perfect game", as understood by the engine used in the analysis. A perfect move will lose zero units of measure.

I couldn't find a chessbase source, but here it is a similar question on lichess, in which the unit of measure is called a centipawn:

https://lichess.org/qa/103/what-is-average-centipawn-loss

Centipawn loss could also be expressed as percentage, but as your question is about precision, they should be the opposite amount. In your example for white, a precision of 93% equals 7 centipawn loss (7% of inaccuracy).

Comment: tl;dr : It doesn't mean much. :)

Comment: @Evargalo The answers in that thread are not too long. Do you mean that precision or centipawn loss measures don't mean much?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean, I think one shouldn't worry too much about these measures, especially precision aggregated on a whole game. But my comment was rather tongue-in-cheek, don't take it too seriously...

Comment: Yes, you are right, the average is not meaningful (unless it's close to the ends).

Comment: Could it be that precision is the percentage of moves that coincide with some engine, running under some unknown parameters?

Comment: @djnavas Do you mean the percentage of moves that coincide exactly with the best move according to that engine? I don't think so, because it would be even more useless, as Evargalo said.